# Javascript datetime value parsing in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 text box controls on my page, one stores the date portion and the other the time portion. The values from both need to be parsed together to have a full datetime value. For example,

control 1: 1/1/2014

control 2: 8:00am

result: 1/1/2014 8:00am

How can i achieve this in javascript or jquery? The result above will be updating the value of a control that is bound to a property on my mvc model but just help on getting the values to combine to form a finished datetime value should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use a hidden field :

```
<input type="hidden" name="fullDate" id="fullDate" value="" />
```

When submitting the form :

```
$("#fullDate").val($("#date").val() + $("#time").val());
```

Where fullDate correspond to a property of your model or a parameter of the function server side.

Comment: This worked just fine, i am sure the below idea would work also

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
var finalDate = control1.getText() + control2.getText();
```

and then use value of finalDate variable